# UIAutomatorViewer not launching [Mac OS Catalina]

Tags: java, android, macos, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I have Android Studio v4.1 installed with Android SDK Platform, API 30. Also Java version installed is: v14.0.2

My Path is set like this:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin   
export PATH  
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:"$PATH"  
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:"$PATH"

#JAVA PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin

#ANDROID PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH

#NODE PATH
export NODE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.14.0/bin/node
export PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin

#HomeBrew sbin path
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Here is the output for echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.14.0/bin/node:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin
```

but when i go to `Android/sdk/tools/bin` , and open one file named `uiautomatorviewer` I am getting this error:

```
~ pratt$ uiautomatorviewer
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 31: dirname: command not found
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 32: basename: command not found
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 38: basename: command not found
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 59: uname: command not found
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 60: [: ==: unary operator expected
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 66: uname: command not found
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 66: [: =: unary operator expected
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 70: expr: command not found
/Users/pratt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer: line 86: //bin/archquery: No such file or directory
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile //
```

Why what is this? I think i have already set up all the paths correctly. Tried deleting and re-installing Android Studio but the same problem happened again. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And if you just try to invoke `dirname` from a command prompt (after setting your `PATH`) does it run the `dirname` program?

Comment: Actually there is something wrong i think. So firstly, I have to delete all my custom paths from the ```.bash_profile``` such that i'm only left with the default paths. Then after saving and reloading using the ```source``` command, then only does it recognise the ```dirname``` or any misc. commands i.e ```rm```

Comment: If i place all my paths in the ```bash_profile``` as mentioned above, then i get errors like ```pratt$ dirname
-bash: dirname: command not found``` OR ```rm
-bash: rm: command not found```